# All combination between 0.01 to 100$ in 4 notes

Tags: combinations

I found this interesting problem: http://mathfactor.uark.edu/2012/07/yoak-denominations-of-money/#comments

> Devise an alternate set of denominations for coins and bank notes
>   requiring a minimum number of denominations and such that any amount
>   from \$0.01 to \$100 could be paid with four units of currency.

I found a smaller upper bound of the one proposed, however I am not sure it is right and I would like someone to check it.

There are 10.000 (from 10000 cent to 1 cent) possible combination of change that we need to express with 4 symbols.

If it was a positional system we would only need $log_4(10.000) <= 7$ symbols.

However we are talking about coins which is not a positional system.

At this point we could just expand the 7 symbols on the 4 bases to get $7 \times 4 = 28$ bank notes.

Which is still an upper bound since $4 ^ 7 = 16384 > 10000$

To make things clearer let me enumerate all the coin I think I need expressed in cent: 
$$
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}  \\
{7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49 } \\
{98, 147, 196, 245, 294, 343, 392} \\
{1029, 1372, 1715, 2058, 2401, 2744, 3087} \\
$$

I am missing something?

Cheers

Comment: Erm, what *are* the denominations you propose?

Comment: Sorry I thought that  was the trivial part, since it is a base system you need 7 for the first digit (0 to 6 each times $7^0=1$), another 7 for the second digit, so (0 to 6 each times $7^1$=7) and so on... Am I wrong?

Comment: Something like $\frac{1}{10}$th of a cent?

Comment: @Siscia Won't you arrive at $7^4$ instead of $4^7$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen humm... There is something I am missing too, but please take a look at the table of the coin... The maximun you can reach is 10290 which is enough...

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Sorry, I didn't get your comment, what you mean?

Comment: @Siscia I was just joking, saying that with a currency of $\frac{1}{10}$th of a cent we could easily have paid everything without change.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, yes, You are right, it would give me $7^4$...